# fresh copy of Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, 19.10

I am not sure what I did wrong. I am fairly new to Unbuntu.

I had Unbuntu 19.10 installed on my laptop. It was running pretty good. I had VLC, Gimp, Wine, Winetricks and ZBrush (through Wine) installed plus whatever comes preinstalled. I was trying to install Kdenlive but was not able to get it to install without problems. I shut down and then all heck broke loose.

I was not able to use it for a few days and when I did it was so very slow that I was waiting 10 plus minutes for it to boot. It just sits on the purple screen. Then when it did boot it would take several minutes to open my files. I tried again to install kdenlive with no luck.

I thought it was because of all the times I installed and uninstalled kdenlive. I thought I should start all over and tried to install a new copy of Ubuntu 19.10. Now it is worse. It installed just fine. Then said It needed updates. Started the updates. Then said to restart. It never restarted.

I found a Ubuntu help that said to open the GRUB menu and go to Advanced options. When I did it showed 2 recovery mode options in the menu. It seems like insead of deleteing partions it just added new os to another partion. I know Windows makes you delete partions when you install it. Not sure how Ubuntu works.

I do not know what to do now. This laptop is only a year old and I think I can never fix it again. Please help.

If you need any other info I missed please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab && cat /etc/mtab && sudo fdisk -l | grep -v loop`

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what this means.

Comment: Run this command in terminal, then edit your question and past its output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure, you don't require disk replacing. Check its health.

But if you want to install your system correctly the next time, select **Something else** during installation:

[image: Something else selection]

During manual disk configuration, assign your old linux partitions to their previous mount points.

But for root partition turn on a **Format** checkbox. **Do not apply it to `/home`** related partition as it is shown on the picture.

[image]

Comment: I already did the fresh install. Should I do it again. The last time it only made it worse. I also do not understand what you said after the image.

Comment: My laptop is stuck on the Ubuntu purple screen. It will not boot. Plus now it won't even read the bootable usb so that I can load a fresh copy of Ubuntu. I wanted to try the partion suggestion above but I am completely stuck now.

Comment: I finally have it booting from the usb drive. Hopefully I can get this to fix the problem.

Comment: Ok. I think I figured something out. The fresh install works. It boots and everything was fine. Right after the fresh install Ubuntu says that there is updates and asks if you want to do the update. It starts to work but when it restarts it gets stuck on the purple Ubuntu screen. Why would updating make it get stuck?

Comment: What is lightdm? I do not understand what that will do.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a dumb thing to say but I just want to be sure. When I turn on my laptop, I wait for the login in page but I don't login. Instead I press crtl+alt+f3. That will bring up the terminal, I think anyway. Then I type  sudo apt install lightdm. When it finishes I type sudo apt budgie-desktop. Then when that is done, I login as usual? Will it run the same as regular Ubuntu? Will wine/etc still install the same? What is tue differnece in the desktops? I am sorry for so many questions. I very much appreciate all of the help you have given me. We really love using Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: I turned the laptop back on and waited forever for it to load to the login screen. Then I pushed ctrl+alt+f3 and my screen went black and had a white line in the top left. I was not able to type anything. Then it went right back to the login screen.

Comment: Everything was working fine. I tried to install kdenlive and then everything went crazy. I am using another computer to reformat my flashdrive and find another ubuntu to use. I really need this laptop to use zbrush through wine and kdenlive. I do not understand a lot of the questions you asked. I am sorry.

Comment: Why kubuntu? Is it better?

Comment: Will Wine run and zbrush through wine?

Comment: kubuntu is a KDE oriented OS and your kdenlive is a KDE Non-Linear Video Editor. It is usual ubuntu, but with KDE instead of Unity. I didn't try zbrush through wine on it). But: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1152

Comment: Ok. I will try kubuntu. If it zbrush doesn't work, I will just use another computer for zbrush and run kdenlive on kubuntu. I really appreciate your help. You have been very patient. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Kubuntu seems to be working. I was able to install kdenlive with no issues. I hope it works as well with wine and zbrush. Thank you again.

Comment: Good! Good luck with wine and zbrush!